# Asp.net #Include external files in content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net application using MasterPages. In the master page I am using Include to incorporate external content.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ResponsiveContentEmpty.master.cs" Inherits="WebUI.MasterPages.ResponsiveContentEmpty" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" class="theme-indigo">
<head>
    <!--#include file="https://www.xxx.gov/TemplatePackage/4.0/includes/head-content.html" -->
    <title>Home | aaa| xxx</title>
</head>
```

When the page runs I get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The given path's format is not supported.

Source Error:


Line 4:  <html lang="en-us" class="theme-indigo">
Line 5:  <head>
Line 6:      <!--#include file="https://www.xxx.gov/TemplatePackage/4.0/includes/head-content.html" -->
Line 7:      <title>Home | aaa| xxx</title>
Line 8:      <link
```

The goal is to include this external content. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inlcude files from another website. If you really want to do that, download that content and inject it in the header.
So place a Literal in the Head of the Master Page.

```
<head runat="server" id="Head1">
    <title>Test</title>

    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
</head>
```

Then in Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        Literal1.Text = client.DownloadString("https://www.xxx.gov/TemplatePackage/4.0/includes/head-content.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is close, but i think the download need to occur at the client. How do I do this in jscript ? My WebApp is cloud hosted and I do not think it will have Internet outbound access